# Отправка e-mail из приложения

Tags: android, java, email

Всем, добрый вечер! Пишу вот такой код для отправки e-mail и смс из своего приложения, смс отправляется, а e-mail - нет. `

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSms:
        // TODO Call second activity
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent
                .putExtra(
                        "sms_body",
                        "Здесь текст и смс прекрасно отправляется!!");
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
        break;
```

case R.id.btnEmail:

```
        /* Создаем интент с экшеном на отправку */
       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        /* Заполняем данными: тип текста, адрес, сабж и собственно текст письма */
        emailIntent.setType("text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Здесь заголовок");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "здесь тоже текст. Но почему-то письмо никак не хочет отправляться???");

        /* Отправляем на выбор!*/
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

        break;

    default:
        break;`
```

Где ошиблась? В манифесте вроде все разрешения прописаны необходимые. Может для e-mail какие-то отдельные permission нужны?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112450/ :

>Минусы: У пользователя должна быть настроенная программа приёма-передачи почтовых сообщений, без неё обрабатывать данный Intent будет некому.

Comment: KaZaца, не очень понятно про программу, должно быть что-то вроде gmail на телефоне или Вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: Да, подразумевается, что должен быть любой почтовый клиент на телефоне, что почти всегда верно(не считая самопала) для отправки писем с помощью Intent-ов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to send email from my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application).

Думаю ошибка в строке:

```
setType("text");
```

Ну и отправка мыла без использования Intent и стороннего клиента:
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a).

Comment: DroidAlex, то есть здесь должно быть setType("text/plain") или setType("message/rfc822");?

Comment: И ещё какая принципиальная разница между Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); и  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);?

Comment: По идеи text/plain должно хватить. Но если ошибка будет - пробуйте второй. На второй вопрос не отвечу так сходу, знаю, что обычно используется ACTION_SEND для отправки писем. И на будущее: ошибки, которые вам среда выводит пишите также в вопрос. Так будет проще понять в чем у вас проблема.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Теперь всё работает - (android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND), и в setType всё-таки ("text/plain");.

Comment: Пожалуйста:)